# Cloud functions in Firebase for Android. В какой IDE писать функции?

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase

Дилетантский вопрос. Впервые сталкиваюсь с JavaScript.
Задача - реализовать серверную функцию для Firebase. Изучил примеры для Cloud functions.
Но вот вопрос: в какой среде разработки создавать index.js? Блокнот это же совсем убого... Есть IDE с конструкторами и подсказками по синтаксису JavaScript для Node?

Comment: Какое отношение тег Java имеет к вопросу?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, видимо целью является андроид приложение, но оно использует firebase, а там надо какие-то функции писать. А метку JS просто забыли добавить)

Comment: Чем нетбинс плоха?  Используй плагин по js и будет тебе счастье

Comment: я писал в notepad++. Конечно, если у вас серьезный функции, то вам такой уровень не подойдет.

Comment: Например можно писать в Android Studio https://stackoverflow.com/a/25109551/5892568